# Empty SIM contacts list, but they still show up in contact details

Tags: contacts, google-account, sim-card

I use solely Google contacts as my contacts repository and display only the Google "My Contacts" group in my contacts list.

When looking at contacts details, most of them have in the "connection" field both the Google and the SIM logo - implying that this is a fusioned contact between Google and the SIM (both small logos are also visible in the contact list).

Strange thing nr 1: When I limit the display to "SIM" only the list is empty. So what does that SIM logo mean?

Strange thing nr 2: in contact details I can separate both contacts (Google and SIM) - I am asked if I really want to separate both contacts and, abracadabra, the SIM contact is gone. The SIM logo is not displayed anymore and the SIM contact list is still empty.

I have no idea how the logos got there, some contacts have it, some others not -- apparently randomly (there is nothing special in contacts which have them and do not -- all are managed from my Google account).

Any ideas on how to fix this (= remove the SIM logo in batch if this is a bug -or- understand what the SIM logo really means)

Than you!

Answer (score 0):

Once you're in the contact list, go into the options.  Your sim contacts are probably filtered.

Comment: No, they are not. As you can see from the description I have dug into the settings but thi sseems to be a bug more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

About SIM contacts: they were copied from the SIM card to the database when you first set-up your Android, and Android does not read automatically your SIM card anymore looking for contacts. If you added more contacts to the SIM card outside of Android (by puting the card onto another phone for example) then you should copy them manually again to the database (there is an option to do so in the contacts app).

I wrote an app that lists all your raw contacts with their belonging account (groups). There you can see how your contacts database is populated: every contact is attached to an account that determines its origin and synchronization, like Google, Facebook, LinkedIn or even SIM and Local Phone. Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brapeba.minicontacts

My app shows you the contacts that there are in the database, but those in the SIM card that never were copied won't show (they don't really exist for Android). To see them, go to the contacts app and choose import from SIM (on some brands you'll see first the list, on others you only have the option to import all them without having a preview).